# How to extract the value of an Input object in Fulma F#?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

im attempting to use Fable's `Input.datetimeLocal` object to receive a start date and end date input from the user. I then want to use these values as the bounds for a slider.

Here is the code:

```
type TimingProps =
    interface end

type TimingState =
    {
      IsStartChecked : bool
      IsEndChecked : bool
      StartDate : string
      EndDate : string
      SliderRatio : int
    }

type TimingInterface(props) =
    inherit Component<TimingProps, TimingState>(props)
    do base.setInitState({ IsStartChecked = false
                           IsEndChecked = false
                           StartDate = "None"
                           EndDate = "None"
                           SliderRatio = 5})



    member this.toggleStartState _ =
        this.setState (fun prevState _ ->
            { prevState with IsStartChecked = not this.state.IsStartChecked}
        )

    member this.toggleEndState _ =
        this.setState (fun prevState _ ->
            { prevState with IsEndChecked = not this.state.IsEndChecked}
        )

    member this.setStartTime (ev : Browser.Types.Event) =
        this.setState (fun prevState _ ->
            let value = unbox<string> ev.currentTarget?value
            { prevState with StartDate = string value }
        )

    member this.setEndTime (ev : Browser.Types.Event) =
        this.setState (fun prevState _ ->
            let value = unbox<string> ev.currentTarget?value
            { prevState with EndDate = value }

        )

    member this.onSlide (ev : Browser.Types.Event) =
        let value = unbox<int> ev.currentTarget?value
        this.setState (fun prevState _ ->
            { prevState with SliderRatio = value }
        )

    override this.render () =
        div [ ClassName "block" ]
            [ Field.div [] [
                Label.label [] [str "Start Time"]
                Checkradio.checkbox
                  [ Checkradio.Checked this.state.IsStartChecked
                    Checkradio.OnChange this.toggleStartState
                    Checkradio.Id "checkradio-1" ]
                      [ str "      End Competition once all users have submitted their ranking (or manually)" ]
                Control.div [ ] [
                if this.state.IsStartChecked then
                  Input.date [ Input.ValueOrDefault "dd/mm/yyyy --:--"
                               Input.OnChange this.setStartTime
                               Input.Disabled true ]
                else
                  Input.datetimeLocal [ Input.OnChange this.setStartTime ]
                ]
              ]
              Field.div [] [
                  Label.label [] [str "End Time"]
                  Checkradio.checkbox
                    [ Checkradio.Checked this.state.IsEndChecked
                      Checkradio.OnChange this.toggleEndState
                      Checkradio.Id "checkradio-2" ]
                        [ str "      End Competition once all users have submitted their ranking (or manually)" ]
                  Control.div [ ] [
                  if this.state.IsEndChecked then
                    Input.datetimeLocal [ Input.ValueOrDefault "dd/mm/yyyy --:--"
                                          Input.OnChange this.setEndTime
                                          Input.Disabled true ]
                  else
                    Input.datetimeLocal [ Input.OnChange this.setEndTime ]
                  ]
              ]
              Field.div [] [
                  Slider.slider [ Slider.OnChange this.onSlide ]
                  div [ ]
                    [ str (sprintf "%A, %A, %A" this.state.SliderRatio  this.state this.state.StartDate) ]
              ]
        ]
```

As you can see at the bottom there, in the final few lines im simply printing the value of the Timing state, just so I can see whats going on. This is what I see when I run the code :

[image: Before I have touched anything]

[image: After providing a value to the 'Start Time']

We can see that the value of `TimingState::StartDate` becomes undefined.

I believe this is a problem with the implementation of the `this.setStartTime` and `this.setEndTime` functions, particularly with how I unbox the events, but I cannot find any documentation anywhere on how to properly use these constructs.

Any help is appreciated!

References:

`Input` Source File : https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/blob/master/src/Fulma/Elements/Form/Input.fs

Answer (score 0):

solved: remove the unboxing of the event value from the lambda (capture the unboxed value instead)